# Extracting text node inside a tag that has a child element in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The HTML that I am parsing and scraping has the following code:

```
<li> <span> 929</span> Serve Returned </li>
```

How can I extract just the text node of `<li>`, "serve returned" in this case with `Beautifulsoup`?

`.string` doesn't work since `<li>` has a child element, and `.text` returns the text inside `<span>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
import bs4
html = r"<li> <span> 929</span> Serve Returned </li>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.li.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)
```

This gives:

```
[u' ', u' Serve Returned ']
```

The first element is the "text" you have before the span. This method could help you find text before and after (and in-between) any child elements.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `str.replace` method for this:

```
>>> li = soup.find('li') # or however you need to drill down to the <li> tag 
>>> mytext = li.text.replace(li.find('span').text, "") 
>>> print mytext
Serve Returned
```